# What can I assume, when given a matrix with information about its eigenvalues but not its action?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Basically, I've had to use linearity a couple of times yesterday and today, in order to write up a few proofs.  But I notice that I am only given information such as positivity conditions and conditions on the matrices' eigenvalues.

...am I allowed to assume that these matrices represent *linear* operators, so that I can actually use the linearity property?  Note: these questions are coming from a linear algebra section of (old) exams.

For example, what if these matrices represent orthogonal operators such as rotations and reflections?  I wouldn't then be able to use linearity, I think.  (cosines and sines as entries in the matrix representation...are certainly not linear entries...)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matrices always represent linear operators, so you can always make this assumption. Even if the entries of a matrix are written as sines or cosines, or another nonlinear function, these functions are evaluated at a point and are ultimately just numbers. For example, a rotation matrix may have $\sin(\pi/4)$ as an entry, but this is just a suggestive way of writing the number $1/\sqrt{2}$. The action of the matrix on vectors is still linear.

Comment: Ahh...yes, that's right - the pi/4, say, for rotation by pi/4 counterclockwise, is fixed in the beginning, before applying the matrix to a vector.  Thanks so much, @AlexS! :-)